# Find matched letter from each word in javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array in  javascript like that :

```
 var books = ['spring','last night','sweet heart','the sky','tomorrow'] ;
```

I have textarea

```
 <textarea id="text" name="textpreview"  class="text"></textarea>
```

So what I want is when I enter letter `s` then I will get two suggestions books just the first word not the second word I mean not `sky` Just `spring` and `sweet heart` .

I will get two spans

```
    <textarea id="text" name="textpreview"  class="text"></textarea>
    <span>spring</span>
    <span>sweet heart</span>
```

If I type again after `s` the `p` letter like `sp` in textarea then I will get just `spring`

```
   <textarea id="text" name="textpreview"  class="text"></textarea>
    <span>spring</span>
```

and so on .

If I type `n` I will get nothing.

If I type `t` I will get `tomorrow` and `the sky`

Hope it can be done . Thanks for your support .

Comment: You should look for an autocompletion plugin, you'll get old to implement by your own

Comment: how about the case that the word book title is 'as the world'? that contains the letter s in the first word

Comment: the first letter should match first from the first word

Comment: To answer your question, it can be done. It's simple to do with angularJS or even vanilla JS. Can you share any code you have written? Easier to help you when you've got a starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This help you :

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="text" name="textpreview"  class="text"></textarea>
        <p id="x"></p>
        <script>
            var x = document.getElementById("x");
            var books = ['spring','last night','sweet heart','last night','the sky','tomorrow','tomorrow'];
            var txt = document.getElementById("text");
            txt.onkeyup = function(event) {
                var str = "";
                var arr = [];
                var index = (txt.value).indexOf("@");
                if(index !== -1 && (txt.value).substr(index + 1).length > 0) {
                        var value = (txt.value).substr(index + 1);
                        value = value.replace(/[\.\+\*\\\?]/g,'\\$&');
                        var patt = new RegExp("^" + value);
                        for(var i=0; i<books.length; i++) {
                            if(patt.test(books[i]) && arr.indexOf(books[i]) === -1) {
                                arr.push(books[i]);
                            }       
                        }
                    }
                if (arr.length < 1 )
                    x.innerHTML = "";
                else {
                    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
                        str+=arr[i]+"<br>";
                    x.innerHTML = str;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: nice but when i type t didnt come tomorrow !

Comment: dear master :) , how could i prevent duplicates if i have `['spring','tomorrow','tomorrow']` so that it will bring just one tomorrow NOT two . thanks for your great help. you can just edit it in your answer.

Comment: @Scooter Daraf , i update my post. your last question send in Other post.please.

Comment: @ScooterDaraf , I update my code. use of  var value = (txt.value).replace(/[\.\^]/,"\\$&"); i insert '.' '^'  you insert other other special characters.

Comment: @ScooterDaraf , check it again!

Comment: @ScooterDaraf, Example?

Comment: @ScooterDaraf , Copy all my code in your editor and run it , no in 'Run code snippet' (no in Editor http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @ScooterDaraf , I've found the problem and solved it.ckeck it again.

Comment: hahaha the bug always there :) , if i write `hgdh  @s` didnt work :) . it works only if its in begining `@s` :)

Comment: @ScooterDaraf , when you type hgdh @s Should not work. when type @s must show 'spring and sweet heart'. what is wrong?

Comment: it should work if i type `@s` even in middle like that `hgdh @s` then it will show sweet heart and spring. or after space like that ` @s`

Comment: i upvoted one comment , and deleted unnesecary comments .

Comment: also escaping this caracter `\\` when using it 2 times it comes error .

Comment: I have escpaed everything in your code like that `value = (value).replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');` and now this problem is solved , its only now when `@s` when is in middle of text like `hgdh @s`

Comment: @ScooterDaraf , I update my post , check it please.i think help you.

Comment: much better version :) but still missing something :) , if i write `@s` works and when i add space  like that `@s ` it works good i mean it dissapear spring and sweet heart so long is good now BUT when i add `@s` like that `@s @s` it will not work the second one . is there something to fix this master ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem consists of two parts: Reading and writing your input/output from/to the DOM, and filtering your array `books`.

The reading and writing part should be easy, there are plenty of guides on how to achieve this.

To filter the `books` array, JavaScript offers a number of helpful functions:

```js
var books = ['spring','last night','sweet heart','the sky','tomorrow'];
var input = 'S';

var result = books.filter(function(book) {
    return book.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) === 0;
}).slice(0, 2);

console.log(result); // ['spring', 'sweet heart']
```

Answer (score 0):

@TimoSta is correct that this is a two-part problem.

I expanded on his code a bit using angular to display the results in the DOM.

http://jsfiddle.net/kcmg9cae/

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <textarea id="text" name="textpreview" class="text" ng-model="startsWith"></textarea>
  <span ng-repeat="book in sortedBooks()">{{ book }}</span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.books = ['spring','last night','sweet heart','the sky','tomorrow'];
    $scope.sortedBooks = function () {
      var sortedBooks = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.books.length; i++){
        if ($scope.books[i].toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.startsWith.toLowerCase()) === 0)
          sortedBooks.push($scope.books[i]);
      }

        return sortedBooks;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is using angular? i hate attaching third part plugins or files which loads much on server, cant be done just js like ehsan do?

Comment: If angular doesn't make sense in your project, don't use it. ehsan's solution could easily be modified to replace the regex with the same conditional logic @TimoSta provided. You have been given a few good concepts to evaluate and learn from. It seems like you may just need to merge the best parts of each to get what you're looking for.